# Solve each system, giving the solution set in vector notation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:
Identify the particular solution and the solution of the homogeneous system.
$$2x + y - z = 1$$
$$4x - y +0z= 3$$

My work:
Leading variable: $x$ and $y$
Free variables: $z$

Express leading variables $x$ and $y$ in terms of free variables $z$.
$$x = (3 + y) / 4$$
$$y = 4x - 3$$
$$z = 2x + y - 1$$

I am stuck at expressing the value of $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ since I need to do eventually write the system in vector notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do RREF (Gaussian Elimination), you have:

$$y = -\dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{2}{3} z$$

$$x = \dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{1}{6} z$$

Can you proceed?

You could have also written $y = 4x-3$ and substituted into the first equation to get $x = \dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{1}{6} z$.

Then, you can find $y$ by substituting in that $x$ into $y = 4x-3$ and this is the same as I show above.

Comment: Ah yes that would be much easier to find y. I see how you got the y value earlier you did -2p1+p2.

Comment: I just solved the second equation for $y$ and sub'ed back into the first. After finding $x$ from that, I sub'ed back into that expression for $y$. Now, I have an expression for $x$ and $y$ in terms of 4z$. Please recall to upvote and/or accept answers that are helpful. Regards

Comment: in regards to the general solution, is the general solution always the vector before the free variable notation? And is the homogeneous system the free variable notation?

Comment: You normally solve the system and then work backward to write the earlier equations in terms of the latter, that is, we try to start writing solution bottoms up after we reduce the system. If you learned RREF, this will make sense.

Comment: okay so first reduce the system using Gauss method until it is in row reduced echelon form and then solve leading variables in terms of free variables.

Comment: Yes, but do it bottom up. In fact, that is how I did for this example and you should repeat that - since you know the result to make sure you get it. Regards

Comment: Oh I see what you mean by bottom up, you wrote y before x.

Comment: Precisely, cause I am reading bottoms up.

Comment: awesome help Amzoti. I should be able to work on similar questions now. =]

Comment: Great work and you are welcome! Regards

Comment: Good ole RREF! +1